# Sum of monthly contributions with contribution growth and interest

Tags: summation, finance

I start with a monthly contribution rate of $200$, which grows at the end of every year by $3\%$. I then know that the sum of all contributions after $40$ years would be $\frac{(200\cdot12)\cdot(1-1.03^{40})}{1-1.03}$ by using the formula for the sum of a geometric progression $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{(1-r)}$

I then add an interest rate to the total amount contributed until then, say $2\%$. So for example we would have:

Year 1: $200\cdot12=2400$

Year 2: $200\cdot12\cdot1.03+2400\cdot1.02=4920$

Year 3: $200\cdot12\cdot1.03^2+4920\cdot1.02=7564.6$

And so on.
I can easily calculate this for 40 years using excel.

My question is, is it possible to get the final sum using a simple formula (so no $\Pi,\Sigma$ sign used)?

I would need it in this fashion in order to plug it into a single excel cell.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you wanted to calculate what you´ve posted?

Comment: @callculus Yes, I think so. I know it's just an approximation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of year $k$, you make a contribution of $200\cdot1.03^k.$  (We start $k$ at $0$.)  It then grows with interest for $40-k$ years, so at the end of year $39$ it has grown to $200\cdot1.03^k1.20^{40-k}$ and the total sum is $$200\cdot1.02^{40}\sum_{k=0}^{39}\left({1.03\over1.02}\right)^k$$

This is a geometric progression, which you already know how to sum.

**EDIT**

Oops, I missed the part about monthly contributions.  It's not clear to me how the bank credits interest though.  Your example makes it seem at though the bank credits interest on all amounts as though they had been contributed at the beginning of the year (most unusual!), in which case, you should just multiply the above answer by $12$.

Comment: I think this is a misinterpretation of the question, which I will paraphrase as follows.  (I will ignore the distinction between months and years made in the question to simplify.)  "I make a contribution in year $k$ which contains two terms.  The first is $1.02^k \cdot 200$.  The second is proportional to everything I have contributed before year $k$.  Is there a nice closed-form expression for the final total after compound interest?"

Comment: I don't understand what you think I misinterpreted.  You make contributions increasing at a rate of $3\%$ and the bank pays compound interest at the rate of $2\%$.  Isn't that so?

Comment: Sorry, I am the one that misinterpreted the question.  I interpreted "I then add" as meaning that the OP was considering a case where he/she makes additional contributions based on the amount that has already been contributed --- but that isn't actually what was meant.